# Accessing "height" property of an instance of a widget

Tags: python, kivy

I need to access the height of a widget after it is created. However, whenever I tried to access `my_widget.height`, it returns the default height of `100` rather than the actual height.

Retrieving `self.height` inside the `on_touch_down` definition of the `my_widget` class works though.

My problem is really best described in the following code.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Layout(BoxLayout):

    # the following yields the correct height of Layout,
    # which is the same as the height of the Window
    def on_touch_down(self, touch): 
        print("inside Layout via on_touch_down:", self.height)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        l = Layout()

        # However, accessing the height here yields the
        # the default height 100
        print("inside MyApp:", l.height)

        return l




if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I spent hours reading different parts of the API doc and the guides on the Kivy website, but couldn't quite find what I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build() method the application has not yet been built so the widget has its default value, so you must obtain that information a moment later, for this there are the following options:

- Use [`App.on_start()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.on_start):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Layout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = Layout()
        return l

    def on_start(self):
        print(self.root.height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

- Use [`Clock.schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Layout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = Layout()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.after_build)
        return l

    def after_build(self, dt):
        print(self.root.height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed this. I posted a follow-up question at the end of my original question. Perhaps you will be so kind as to clarify it for me...again :D.

Comment: @omichael If you have another question then create a new post, in that question you can point to this question / answer to follow up.