# Getting the "height" property of a custom widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

This is a follow-up question for [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541856/accessing-height-property-of-an-instance-of-a-widget/)

When I create a custom widget defined in kv language, I cannot access the actual height of the widget. Whenever I do so, I get `0`. The actual height can be seen by retrieving `self.height` in the widget's `.on_touch_down`. The problem is best described in the code.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<Item>:

    size_hint: 1, None
    height: lil.height

    Label:
        id: lil
        top: root.top
        x: root.x

        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size

        font_size: 90
        text: "Testing123"
''')

class Layout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Item(Widget):
    # This yields the correct height
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(self.height)



l = Layout()
li = Item()

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        l.add_widget(li)

        return l

    def on_start(self):
        # This yields the incorrect height
        print(li.height)
        print(self.root.children[0].height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a binding the properties can change at various times, in your case you are getting 0 because at that time all the internal elements are not yet built so the binding has no effect, so if you want to get the size you must track the binding:

```py
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l.add_widget(li)
        li.bind(height=self.height_callback)

        return l

    def height_callback(self, *args):
        print(li.height)
```

Output:

```
848
106
```

Comment: is there a event for when a widget is completely built? @eyllanesc

Comment: @omichael Saying "completely built" is subjective and in reality it has been since you created the object but its properties are dynamic, for example you have seen that the height property takes different values and this may change in the future. I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you want to get the "final height"?

Comment: I want to get the height so that I can position multiple items based on their heights. The height of each item may change based on the text-wrapping of the label inside that item, therefore, the position needs to change too. In other words, I am trying to make a list of items that stack nicely on top of each other. I could have used a Boxlayout instead of a Floatlayout, but I also want to try implementing some sort of "drag-n-drop", so I am experimenting different ways to do it right now. You answer really helps though, and has already solved my problem.

Comment: @omichael The simplest solution is to make a binding either in .py: `obj.bind(height=...)`or in .kv: `height: lil.height`

Comment: You are right. Another way is to use `Clock.schedule_once()` to delay the positioning just a little, like you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541948/5043611). I got it now. Thanks!